# In magento1.9,I want to track commission and transaction done by social site in affiliate marketing?

Tags: magento-1.9, social-buttons, affiliate

When customer doing shopping through affiliate sharing the link by Facebook or another social site then **how to track affiliate commission and transaction done by social sites?**

I am using `magebuzz affiliate extension.`

Comment: track affiliation id when user visit your landing page..  use  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']   track url

Answer (score 0):

If you have paid for a module you should better ask for any technical support there

Anyways, have you checked User Guide? http://www.magebuzz.com/media/userguide/magento1_affiliate_userguide.pdf

There is a **Track Transaction** section, which seems to be what you are asking for

Comment: Actually i send many queries but they didn't give any support.so i am facing many problems.

Comment: But... you'd understand people can't give support if they can't see the code

Comment: yaa i know.but there is any extention for social site sharing?